# PHP: Load a class in a class

Tags: php, class, oop, subclass

I have a class which is meant to *"load"* an another class, however I haven't been able to get it to work.

### Error Message

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::echoString() in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\classes\example.php on line 5`

### Code

My code is broken up into three main sections:

- `api.php` -  the class to load the other classes.
- `API/exampleExternalAPI.php` - (multiple files) the classes that `api.php` loads
- `example.php` - the file that uses the main class (`api.php`)

If it helps these files can be downloaded from my [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/41kdykwv3n0pzeu/AAC2Zw34NA26MBsjcnnsNXEAa?dl=0)

#### api.php

```
<?php
/* Config */
define('pathToAPIs','API/');

/* Autoload Function */
spl_autoload_register(function($className){
    $namespace=str_replace("\\","/",__NAMESPACE__);
    $className=str_replace("\\","/",$className);
    $class=pathToAPIs.(empty($namespace)?"":$namespace."/")."{$className}.php";
    include_once($class);
});

class api {
    private $listOfAPIs;

    public $APIs;

    public function __construct($setAPI = null){
        $this->updateListOfAPIs();
        if (isset($setAPI)){
            return $this->setAPI($setAPI);
        }
    }
    public function setAPIs($setAPIs){
        $this->APIs = null; // clears a previous call to this method
        if (!is_array($setAPIs)){ // if not an array
            $setAPIs = array($setAPIs); // make array
        }
        foreach ($setAPIs as $setAPIType){
            if(in_array($setAPIType,$this->listOfAPIs)){
                $array[$setAPIType] = new $setAPIType;
            }
        }
        $this->APIs = json_decode(json_encode($array), FALSE); // convert array of required api objects to an object
        return $this->APIs;
    }
    public function getListOfAPIs($update = false){
        if ($update){
            $this->updateListOfAPIs();
        }
        return  $this->listOfAPIs;
    }
    private function updateListOfAPIs(){
        $this->listOfAPIs = null; // clears a previous call to this method
        $it = new FilesystemIterator(pathToAPIs);
        foreach ($it as $fileinfo){
            $filename = pathinfo($fileinfo->getFilename(), PATHINFO_FILENAME); // removes extension
            $this->listOfAPIs[]= $filename;
        }
    }
    public function __call($method,$args){

    }
}
```

#### API/exampleExternalAPI.php

```
<?php

class exampleExternalAPI {

       public function echoString($string){
           echo $string;
       }
}
```

#### example.php

```
<?php
require_once 'api.php';
$api = new api();
$api->setAPIs('exampleExternalAPI');
$api->APIs->exampleExternalAPI->echoString('string');
```

### Background Info

(may give some insight to my madness)

- I'm working on a project where I need to connect to lots of external APIs.
- So I decided to creating a class to look after all my communications with external APIs  ( not sure if best way - new to Object Oriented Programming).

Comment: You shouldn't load a class inside another one. You should be extending classes, and using a PHP file to organize calls to various classes. Like if you use the MVC pattern, then your controller or models can make calls to the various APIs you are using.

Comment: Why are you using `json_decode(json_encode(...))`? That will destroy any types other than those supported in JSON.

Comment: @Pierre-EmmanuelLevesque ahh i hadn't thought of doing it that way - i thought a class couldn't be extended by multiple classes at once, ie multiple apis

Comment: @Ja͢ck i initially wasn't but i couldn't get this [code](http://pastebin.com/uCFNji7E) to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what problem you're trying to solve, but if your `APIs` is a simple `stdClass` instance it should work as expected:

```
public function setAPIs($setAPIs)
{
    $this->APIs = new stdClass; // clears a previous call to this method
    if (!is_array($setAPIs)) { // if not an array
        $setAPIs = array($setAPIs); // make array
    }
    foreach ($setAPIs as $setAPIType) {
        if (in_array($setAPIType, $this->listOfAPIs)) {
            $this->APIs->{$setAPIType} = new $setAPIType;
        }
    }
    return $this->APIs;
}
```

Comment: thanks, the problem I have is when I run `example.php` i get a fatal error

Comment: @jamesmstone The fatal error in your question doesn't apply to this answer.

Comment: No this fatal error doesn't apply to your answer, but this answer also doesn't solve my problem - the fatal error.

--- On a side note how do I tag you ( Jack ) in a comment :P  `@Jack` dosent work

Comment: @jamesmstone Not sure I understand, if I run your code with my answer it will output "string"; if that's not what you wanted, I would suggest changing the question.

Comment: That is what I want! - hmmm for some reason it isn't working with me then.

Comment: @jamesmstone I've reduced the code to just [this](http://pastebin.com/paPCm0fE) and it works.